# placing string into sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've created a table in android. when i try to add or take any data it crashes .. what could be the problem ??

code on which crashes:

```
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_STRING,KEY_rewID }, 
                null, null, null, null, null);
```

i add here an row in table :

```
database.insert("1", encodedImageString, "8");
                System.out.println(sqlite_obj.getAllData());
```

log cat :

```
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: photos (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, photostring, reviewID FROM photos
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at com.project.sqlite.PhoDB.getAllData(PhoDB.java:95)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at com.project.simplify.Photo_upload$3.onClick(Photo_upload.java:133)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-24 01:23:58.110: E/AndroidRuntime(9766):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)









 public class PhoDB {

    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_STRING = "photostring";
    public static final String KEY_rewID = "reviewID";

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PhotoDB";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "photos";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 99;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table sample (id text primary key,reviewID text not null  ,photostring text not null);";

    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public PhoDB(Context ctx) {

        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sample");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    //---open SQLite DB---
    public PhoDB open() throws SQLException {

        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---close SQLite DB---
    public void close() {

        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert data into SQLite DB---
    public long insert(String id, String photo_string, String reviewID) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_ID, id);
        initialValues.put(KEY_STRING, photo_string);
        initialValues.put(KEY_rewID, reviewID);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---Delete All Data from table in SQLite DB---
    public void deleteAll() {

        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
    }

    //---Get All Contacts from table in SQLite DB---
    public Cursor getAllData() {

        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_STRING,KEY_rewID }, 
                null, null, null, null, null);
    }


}
```

Comment: Your database table doesn't exist

Comment: i call these methods in onCreate :
database = new PhoDB(Photo_upload.this);
  database.open();

Comment: Your `create` statement is creating a table named `sample`, not `photos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating table with different name .

Change :

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table sample (id text primary key,reviewID text not null  ,photostring text not null);";
```

with :

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE +" (id text primary key,reviewID text not null  ,photostring text not null);";
```

Comment: You might want to point out that the `onUpgrade()` method references the `sample` table, too.

Comment: @MikeM. yes good point . user3416113 you should basicly use one approach , use your static DATABASE_TABLE variable instead of typing your datebase table everytime